# Check if $(\mathbb Z_7, \odot)$ is an abelian group, issue in finding inverse element

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups

Take $\mathbb Z_7$ and the operation $\odot$ defined on it as follows $\forall a,b \in \mathbb Z_7$:

$$\begin{aligned} a \odot b=a+b+3\end{aligned}$$

Check if $(\mathbb Z_7, \odot)$ is a group and in particular if it is an abelian group.

**Associativity**

It can be easily proved that $\odot$ is associative:

$$\begin{aligned} (a \odot b) \odot c = a \odot (b \odot c)\end{aligned}$$
$$\begin{aligned}(a + b + 3) \odot c = a \odot (b+c+3)\end{aligned}$$ 
$$\begin{aligned} (a + b + 3) + c +3 = a + (b+c+3)+3 \end{aligned}$$
$$\begin{aligned} a + b + c +6 = a +b+c+6 \end{aligned}$$

**Commutativity**

$\odot$ is commutative:

$$\begin{aligned} a \odot b = b \odot a \end{aligned}$$
$$\begin{aligned} a + b + 3 = b +a+3 \end{aligned}$$

**Identity element**

There is an identity element for $(\odot, \mathbb Z_7)$

$$\begin{aligned} a \odot \mathbb 1_{\mathbb Z_7} = a \end{aligned}$$
$$\begin{aligned} a + e + 3 = a \end{aligned}$$
$$\begin{aligned} e + 3 = 0 \end{aligned}$$
$$\begin{aligned} e = 4 \end{aligned}$$

and similarly if we repeat the calculation for $\mathbb 1_{\mathbb Z_7} \odot a$, still $e=4$

What I am struggling with is the inverse element, how to check if there is one. I know that it should be:

$$\begin{aligned} a \odot a^{-1} = e \\ a + a^{-1} + 3 = e \\ a + a^{-1} + 3 = 4\end{aligned}$$

Is it acceptable to state $a^{-1} = a+1$ (and similarly for $a^{-1} \odot a = e$)? If so, have I succeeded in proving $(\odot, \mathbb Z_{7})$ to be an abelian group?

Comment: $a^{-1}=1-a=1+6a$ that is $a^{-1}=(1+6a)$ mod 7 isnt it ?

Comment: No, it's not acceptable to state that $a+1$ is the inverse of $a$, since it's not true. For example, take $a=1$. Then $a\odot (a+1)=1\odot 2=1+2+3=6\neq 4$.

Comment: Note you did not prove the alleged group has an identity. What you *did* prove is that if it does have an identity, then the identity is 4. It's unclear if you have the same conceptual mistake for your proofs of the other properties.

Comment: @Hurkyl what about the associativity, commutativity and identity element? If my calculation is right and all of those apply along with the presence of the inverse elements isn't that enough to say that $(\mathbb Z_7, \odot)$ is an abelian group? If not what am I missing?

Comment: @haunted85: Your proof outline is fine: the individual steps are true (once you've corrected your typo for inverses) and the conclusion holds. However, the way you did the "prove it has an identity" step is backwards, and I suspect you did the other two steps backwards as well (but I can't know for sure without knowing your actual thoughts about what you were doing).

Comment: @Hurkyl ok, it may seem I did it backwards, but I do the exercise on paper first then I show you guys my results, so I guess I anticipated the conclusion as I copied the calculations on screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inverse is $a^{-1}=1-a$, as $a\odot (1-a)=a+(1-a)+3=4=e$.

Answer (score 5):

We have $\rm\:a + a^{-1} = 1,\:$ so $\rm\: a^{-1} = 1 - a.\:$ All of your equations should be connected by arrows going *both* ways $(\!\!\iff\!\!)$ since you need to prove equivalences (necessity *and* sufficiency).

Here the group structure arises simply from renaming (or labeling) the elements of the additive group $\,\Bbb Z/7\,$ via the "label" *bijection* $\rm\:\ell\, n := n-3,\:$ i.e. by naming or labeling each natural mod $7\,$ by the natural congruent to $\rm\,n\!-\!3.\,$ To perform an operation on labels, we first unlabel arguments by applying $\,\mu\,n:=\ell^{-1}n\, =\, \rm n\!+\!3,\,$ then perform the operation in $\Bbb Z/7,\,$ then label the result, i.e.

$$ a \oplus b\ :=\  \ell\,(\ell^{-1}a\, +\, \ell^{-1}b)\ =\rm\, -3 + ((a\!+\!3) + (b\!+\!3))\ =\ a+b+3 $$

$$ \ominus\, a\ :=\ \ell(-\,\ell^{-1}a)\ =\rm\ {-}3+ (-(a\!+\!3))\ =\ {-}6-a\ =\ 1-a\qquad $$

Thus we have $\, \mu(a \oplus b)\, =\, \mu\,a + \mu\, b,\ $ and $\, \mu(\ominus a)\, =\, -\mu\, a\ $ so $\,\mu\,$ is a bijective group homomorphism, hence an isomorphism. In more technical language we say that we have *transported the group structure* along the bijection $\,\ell\,$ (or $\,\mu = \ell^{-1})$.

For example the equation $\,5+ 6 = 4\,$ transports to $\,\ell\, 5 \oplus \ell\, 6 = \ell\, 4,\,$ i.e. $\it\, 2 \oplus 3 =  1,\,$ and $\,-(5)\, =\, 2\,$ goes to $\,\ominus(\ell\,5)\, =\, \ell\, 2,\,$ i.e. $\it\,\ominus\:\!2 = 6.\,$ Transporting the whole  addition table yields

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline  
\color{#C00}\oplus &\it\color{#C00}0 &\it\color{#C00}1 &\it\color{#C00}2 &\it\color{#C00}3 &\it\color{#C00}4 &\it\color{#C00}5 &\it\color{#C00}6 \\ \hline 
\it\color{#C00} 0 &\it 3 &\it 4 &\it 5 &\it 6 &\it 0 &\it 1 &\it 2 \\ \hline 
\it\color{#C00} 1 &\it 4 &\it 5 &\it 6 &\it 0 &\it 1\, &\it 2 &\it 3 \\ \hline
\it\color{#C00} 2 &\it 5 &\it 6 &\it 0 &\it 1\, &\it 2 &\it 3 &\it 4 \\ \hline
\it\color{#C00} 3 &\it 6 &\it 0 &\it 1\, &\it 2 &\it 3 &\it 4 &\it 5 \\ \hline
\it\color{#C00} 4 &\it 0 &\it 1\, &\it 2 &\it 3 &\it 4 &\it 5 &\it 6 \\ \hline
\it\color{#C00} 5 &\it 1\, &\it 2 &\it 3 &\it 4 &\it 5 &\it 6 &\it 0 \\ \hline
\it\color{#C00} 6 &\it 2 &\it 3 &\it 4 &\it 5 &\it 6 &\it 0 &\it 1\, \\ \hline
\end{array}
\ \ \begin{array}{c}
\xrightarrow[\large \ \it N\ \to\,\rm N+3\ ]{\large \rm unlabel\,\ \mu}
\\
\\ \\
\xleftarrow[\large \ \it N-3\ \leftarrow\, \rm N\ ]{\large \rm label\,\ \ell}
\end{array}\ \ 
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline
\color{#C00}+ &\color{#C00} 3 &\color{#C00} 4 &\color{#C00} 5 &\color{#C00} 6 &\color{#C00} 0 &\color{#C00} 1 &\color{#C00} 2 \\ \hline
\color{#C00}3 & 6 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ \hline
\color{#C00}4 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ \hline
\color{#C00}5 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 0 \\ \hline
\color{#C00}6 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 0 & 1 \\ \hline
\color{#C00}0 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\ \hline
\color{#C00}1 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline
\color{#C00}2 & 5 & 6 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Note that the addition table on the right is that for addition mod $7$, except the rows and columns have been permuted (shifted by $3$). Thus the two addition tables are essentially the same, i.e. they differ only in the names chosen for the elements. This is the sense of isomorphism that is captured by the notion of *isomorphic groups*, i.e. the two groups have exactly the same operation tables (up to order), i.e. they are identical after a (renaming) bijection is applied to the elements. This notion of algebraic isomorphism (sameness) is defined so that an algebraic structure is determined completely by its operation tables, i.e. **the only properties of the elements that we care about algebraically are how the elements relate to each other under the operations**. Any other (internal) structure the elements may possess (names, set-theoretic representation, etc), play no role algebraically (this is elaborated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/221626/242)).

Similarly we can transport the group structure along any permutation $\,\ell\,$ of $\,\Bbb Z/7$, and we can label or index any finite group by natural numbers (e.g. which might be addresses in computer memory, where (un)label operations amounts to memory (de)references).

Comment: Irrelevant, but you write good answers. Just appreciating. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I just added a table of your group. Maybe it helps you a little bit. Other comments and answer is enough for your question.

[image]

Comment: pictures, graphs, tables, etc always help! +